# Can I read or update dynamically the multiple Mule app properties without reloading or restarting?

Tags: properties, mule, reload

We are planning to create a application that reads all the properties file associated to the mule application running in server.
Our intention to read the properties and update from the custom application instead of providing access to the MMC.
Users can update the Quartz Time schedule, Reschedule, Pause and Resume Jobs and Triggers.

Can we create an application and run in parallel to Mule Instance deployment and read all application properties and update dynamically with out effecting the deployment ( No restart and deployment).

Comment: I think this would be very tricky and would involve refreshing the entire Mule and Spring Contexts, in theory possibly but in practice possibly not ... but I am not a expert  on Mule internals :), so don't take my word on it

Comment: @sashidhar Do you want to create parallel application in Mule for reading the properties file ???

Comment: Thanks David, Even I thought same. Need some more details like how we can write property file into specific application path and reload into the running application without restarting server. I would like to know how initially application properties loaded into cache and when we overwrite the properties how it will be reloaded into the running application.

Comment: Yes @Anirban, I am trying to create parallel application that reads and overwrites the properties without restarting.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no:

The reason why you can't do this is because many components have a special lifecycle and bring up server sockets or connect to jms queues upon that configuration, so even if you change the properties you would least at a bare minimum stop and start the respective components so the previous resources are released and new ones acquired.

Answer (score 0):

The properties file change cannot be detected until the Mule XML is changed. So an alternet option to read the changes in the 
properties file is to change some thing in Mule XML and save it.

When ever the Mule server detect any changes in the XML file, 
XML is read and the mule context is created. This has already been discussed here :- http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/can-we-reload-properties-without-restarting-application

So if you want to create an application in Mule to read the updated value from properties you always need that application to do some changes in your Mule XML